# How to Set Timer for check Internet Connection on a WebKitView in ios

Tags: ios, swift, timer

I am using RechabilitySwift(https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift) library.I am prompting user with a message using UIAlertController,if Internet connection is not available.How can I set timer for network connection retry on the webview.

Comment: Could you talk a little bit more about your flow. It sounds like if you simply observe when connection comes and goes it could lead to a frustrating user experience for your user. Imagine those users on a train going in and out of tunnels. Simply throwing an alert on the absence of connection is going to frustrate your users. Have you thought about, displaying a simple banner instead, or only throwing the alert when the user attempts to access a network resource that has no fallback resource locally?

Comment: flow:-I am loading the webView on click of a button -> if network disconnect -> Timer start say for 15 sec(say)  message pop up(Retrying connect to network)->if network connect in between ->timer hides and webView will be load again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you should use notification or observer instead,

for notification you can try this code

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:Selector(("checkForReachability:")), name: 
NSNotification.Name.reachabilityChanged, object: nil)
let reachability: Reachability = Reachability.forInternetConnection()
reachability.startNotifier()
```

Comment: I am using this.